# PHP API call, using access token as a variable in simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm trying to write a very simple bit of php that parses some XML data from an API call.

I've got the xml parsing down (not real details):

```
   $myevents = simplexml_load_file("https://www.eiseverywhere.com/api/v2/ereg/getEvent.xml?accesstoken=34673483734734734&eventid=3483483");    echo $myevents->location[0]->name;
```

My issue is with the authentication for the API call the api (like most) requires each call uses an access token created on the fly using this (not real data):

```
   $mynumber = simplexml_load_file("https://www.eiseverywhere.com/api/v2/global/authorize.xml?accountid=7834&key=214lkh21lkh412kh212");
```

This returns the access token as xml, I want to set that token as a variable for use in the first call, but when I use the following, it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$mynumber = simplexml_load_file("https://www.eiseverywhere.com/api/v2/global/authorize.xml?accountid=6236&key=okil3h613oj2o3ji5h2oih");

echo $mynumber->accesstoken;


$myevents = simplexml_load_file("https://www.eiseverywhere.com/api/v2/ereg/getEvent.xml?accesstoken=$mynumber&eventid=124124");

echo $myevents->location[0]->name;

?>
```

Sorry if this seems totally wrong, this is my first day with PHP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you are using the xml object as the access token, not the actual string token.

```
<?php 
// change this line
$myevents = simplexml_load_file("https://www.eiseverywhere.com/api/v2/ereg/getEvent.xml?accesstoken=$mynumber&eventid=124124");

// to this    
$token = $mynumber->accesstoken;
$myevents = simplexml_load_file("https://www.eiseverywhere.com/api/v2/ereg/getEvent.xml?accesstoken={$token}&eventid=124124");
?>
```

Welcome to PHP! :)